# Can I get default template argument from template specialization with clang AST?

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to get default template argument from a template specialization with clang AST, but can find no way.

Can anyone help me?

```
template<typename TT0>
struct DefaultArg
{
  typedef char TypeT;
};

template<typename TT0,
     typename TT1 = typename DefaultArg<TT0>::TypeT >
struct Template0
{
};

Template0<int> s; // Is there any way to get 'DefaultArg<int>::TypeT'
              // ( neither DefaultArg<TT0>::TypeT nor 'char'   )
              // as default template argument
              // for this template specialization?
```

[AST dump for the sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjSJn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: not to my knowledge.

Work around solution...
Here is example code that does the trick:
*(it only works for depth=0)*

```cpp
bool CheckSpecializedTemplate(const clang::QualType& Type)
{
    // ignore types that are not class or struct records
    if (!Type->isRecordType() || !Type->isStructureOrClassType())
        return false;

    // get the underlying record and make sure it is a
    // specialization of a template type
    const clang::CXXRecordDecl* Record = Type->getAsCXXRecordDecl();
    if (Record->getKind() != clang::Decl::Kind::ClassTemplateSpecialization)
        return false;

    return true;
}


bool TrySubstitutionPrint(
    const clang::TemplateParameterList* TemplateList,
    const clang::TemplateArgumentList& ArgumentsList,
    const clang::QualType& Type)
{
    //
    // Hack to patch in the type substitutions
    // (AST doesn't seem to preserve dependent template specialization)
    //

    auto& out = llvm::outs();

    // from the dependent type, get the nested type or return
    const clang::Type* Ptr = Type.getTypePtr();
    if (Ptr->getTypeClass() != clang::Type::TypeClass::DependentName)
        return false;
    const clang::DependentNameType* DnPtr =
        static_cast<const clang::DependentNameType*>(Ptr);
    const clang::NestedNameSpecifier* Nns = DnPtr->getQualifier();
    if (!Nns) return false;
    if (Nns->getKind() != clang::NestedNameSpecifier::SpecifierKind::TypeSpec)
        return false;
    const clang::Type* NestedPtr = Nns->getAsType();
    if (NestedPtr->getTypeClass() != clang::Type::TypeClass::TemplateSpecialization)
        return false;

    const clang::TemplateSpecializationType* TsPtr =
        static_cast<const clang::TemplateSpecializationType*>(NestedPtr);
    const clang::TemplateDecl* Temp = TsPtr->getTemplateName().getAsTemplateDecl();

    out << DnPtr->getKeywordName(DnPtr->getKeyword()).str();
    out << " " << Temp->getNameAsString() << "<";

    // match the args to their respective parameters
    const clang::TemplateParameterList* List = Temp->getTemplateParameters();
    bool Multi = false;
    for (auto Token = List->begin(); Token != List->end(); Token++) {
        if (Multi) out << ", "; else Multi = true;
        out << (*Token)->getNameAsString();

        // brute force search
        int Index = 0;
        for (auto T2 = TemplateList->begin(); T2 != TemplateList->end(); T2++) {
            if ((*T2)->getNameAsString() == (*Token)->getNameAsString()) {
                out << " = " << ArgumentsList[Index].getAsType().getAsString();
                break;
            }
            Index++;
        }
    }
    out << ">::";

    // print the dependent type name
    const clang::IdentifierInfo* identifier = DnPtr->getIdentifier();
    out << identifier->getName().str();

    return true;
}


bool VisitVarDecl(clang::VarDecl* Decl)
{
    auto& out = llvm::outs();
    clang::QualType Type = Decl->getType();

    // let's only look for variables with name "s"
    auto varname = Decl->getNameAsString();
    if (varname != "s") return true;

    // we only want specialized templates
    if (!CheckSpecializedTemplate(Type)) return true;

    // convert the record to a specialization and
    // get the underlying template decl
    const clang::CXXRecordDecl* Record = Type->getAsCXXRecordDecl();
    const clang::ClassTemplateSpecializationDecl* Special =
        static_cast<const clang::ClassTemplateSpecializationDecl*>(Record);
    const clang::ClassTemplateDecl* Template = Special->getSpecializedTemplate();

    // iterate over the list of template parameters and print them out
    const clang::TemplateArgumentList& ArgsList =
        Special->getTemplateArgs();
    const clang::TemplateParameterList* TemplateList =
        Template->getTemplateParameters();
    int Index = 0;
    for (clang::TemplateParameterList::const_iterator
        TemplateToken = TemplateList->begin();
        TemplateToken != TemplateList->end(); TemplateToken++)
    {
        switch ((*TemplateToken)->getKind()) {
        case clang::Decl::Kind::TemplateTemplateParm: {
            const clang::TemplateArgument& c = ArgsList[Index];
            out << "class = " << c.getAsType().getAsString();
        } break;

        case clang::Decl::Kind::TemplateTypeParm: {
            const clang::TemplateTypeParmDecl* ttpd =
                static_cast<const clang::TemplateTypeParmDecl*>(*TemplateToken);

            if (ttpd->hasDefaultArgument()) {
                clang::QualType DefaultArg = ttpd->getDefaultArgument();
                if (!TrySubstitutionPrint(TemplateList, ArgsList, DefaultArg))
                    out << DefaultArg.getAsString() << "+";
            }
            else out << "template " << ttpd->getNameAsString();

            const clang::TemplateArgument& c = ArgsList[Index];
            out << " = " << c.getAsType().getAsString();
        } break;
        }
        out << "\n";
        Index++;
    }

    // All done!
    out << "\n";
    return true;
}
```

The output for your code snippet would be

```
template TT0 = int
typename DefaultArg<TT0 = int>::TypeT = char
```